# R: Ryacas package not working properly on Mac

Tags: r

I can't get the Ryacas package to work on Mac. I keep getting this error:

```
[1] "Starting Yacas!"
In> Error in socketConnection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 9734, server = FALSE,  :  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 9734, server = FALSE,  : 127.0.0.1:9734 cannot be opened
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First things first: Have you installed Yacas?

Comment: Read theTtroubleshooting section of this page: https://code.google.com/archive/p/ryacas/

Comment: It seems to be a permissions issue.

Comment: This is the error I get when installing it from the terminal `code Making install in .
/bin/sh ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
 /usr/bin/install -c yacas_client /usr/local/bin/yacas_client
install: /usr/local/bin/yacas_client: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-binSCRIPTS] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 `

Comment: What did you do to try to install it?  Are you able to install other packages?